# Use Views to delete a record from the database

Tags: views, userpoints

I have created a view that displays userpoints info. What I need is to create a link that will delete or reset individual records.

Answer (score 5):

Userpoints can not be deleted, at least not through the UI.

Instead, you need to create a reverting transaction that removes the points that the other transaction added, or the other way round.

The only thing that you can currently do out of the box is building a link that points to the add points form with the username pre-filled, by using that as a token in views. Then you just need to add the points and save.

Everything else currently requires custom code, by e.g. writing a custom action.

Userpoints 7.x-2.x will allow this using bulk operations and better rules integration, but there is currently not much progress on that branch. As in, pretty much none.

Comment: I was thinking if there is a reset all button there should be a reset this one user point. I desperately need this. :-(

Comment: Could you elaborate on prefilling the users name in the add form?

Comment: You need to build an url that points to admin/config/people/userpoints/add/[uid], which should be able to using views tokens.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the database where all the information about your website is stored (when you're using phpMyAdmin for example), you can navigate to **your_database > userpoints/userpoints_total/userpoints_txn** and delete all the granted User Points you want to. There's a nice 'select all' link at the bottom if you'd need to delete a lot of data.

It worked for me, but be careful with this: all deleted data will be lost forever! Therefore, make sure you always back-up before deleting stuff from your database!